# Navigation Controller Custom Direction Not Changing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to get the navigation controller direction to be `kCATransitionFromTop` with the `CATransition` and it is set up to do that however for some reason it is still going from right to left.  The fade portion works perfectly.  Is there anything that I am doing wrong to have this not work?  Do I need to add code in the other view controller? Thanks

```
- (void)bottomButtonScreen4:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

        settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];

        CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.5;
        transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        transition.type = kCATransitionFromTop;
        [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:settingsViewController animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type should be push, and the subtype kCATransitionFromBottom (which actually makes it come in from the top):

```
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:settingsViewController animated:NO];
```

Comment: Hi! This works but it still transitions right to left as well as from bottom to top.  Any reason why it does both transitions?

Comment: @GrantWilkinson, did you set animated to NO? When I tried it, it came down from the top. You don't have a segue hooked up to the gesture recognizer do you?

Comment: You're right thank you! I didn't have the set animated to no.  Works great now.  Thank you again

Comment: One last quick thing, when the new controller gets loaded in, the controller loads but the view of that controller does not.  What do I need to add to get the view loaded that i have on my storyboard?

Comment: @GrantWilkinson, you need to instantiate it properly -- if it's in a storyboard you don't want to do alloc init, you want to do [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"]; pass what ever identifier you set for the controller in the storyboard.

Comment: I did that and unfortunately that still leaves it black.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @GrantWilkinson, I can't tell without seeing more of your code. I tested the code I posted, and that is what I did to instantiate the controller, and I got the correct view.

Comment: kCATransitionFromBottom is making transition from top to bottom for me.Why is it so?This is for UIView.